# Can not get @@ERROR after EXEC() with Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Please see the following t-sql code

```
   DECLARE @iError INT
   EXEC('select * from sysobj')
   SELECT @iError = @@ERROR
   PRINT 'Error = ' + CAST(@iError AS VARCHAR(10))
```

After I run it, it returns error message, which is what I want.

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'sysobj'.
>   Error = 208

However, if I change the query

```
   DECLARE @iError INT
   EXEC('select * from sysobjects where ''c'' = 1')
   SELECT @iError = @@ERROR
   PRINT 'Error = ' + CAST(@iError AS VARCHAR(10))
```

The output will be

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'c' to data type int.

The problem is any code afer EXEC() is not executed.

In the real stored procedure, I have some code to handle the errors after PRINT. And none of those code executed in second case.

Could someone let me know why this happens?

I tested it on both SQL Server 2008 and 2005.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to show us the code you are trying and failing to run. Is it in a try Catch block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different errors will have different levels of abort and some of these can be controlled through the use of settings, like ARITHIGNORE and ANSI_WARNINGS.

I suggest reading the following article that explains all of this in great detail.

http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#whathappens

Statement-termination and Batch-abortion

These two groups comprise regular run-time errors, such as duplicates in unique
indexes, running out of disk space etc. As I have already have discussed, which
error that causes which action is not always easy to predict beforehand. This
table lists some common errors, and whether they abort the current
statement or the entire batch.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's an article on this on msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175921%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx).  It has to do with the context in which the `EXEC()` statement is run.  If you include the error trap in the parameter passed to `EXEC()`, you can stuff it into a temp table and then look at that.

Here's their example:

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(1000), @ExecError INT

CREATE TABLE #ErrFile (ExecError INT)

SET @cmd = 'EXEC GetTableCount ' + 
'''pubs.dbo.authors''' + 
'INSERT #ErrFile VALUES(@@ERROR)'

EXEC(@cmd)

SET @ExecError = (SELECT * FROM #ErrFile)

SELECT @ExecError AS '@@ERROR'
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into implementing [TRY...CATCH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for your error handling. You should be able to put all of your error handling in the CATCH block then.

Comment: Thanks Joe. Yes, I changed the code with TRY/CATCH, and it works. Just want to know why this happens.